NodeJS is not executing the middleware, when the thread pool is completely occupied
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const { reelsRoutes } = require("./routes");

const app = express();

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "video_files")));

app.use("/reels", reelsRoutes);

let globalCount = 1;

app.use("/test", (req, res) => {
  let count = globalCount++;
  const keyLength = 64;
  const digest = "sha512";

  const startTime = Date.now();

  console.log(count, " ", startTime);

  crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 25000000, keyLength, digest, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("pbkdf2 ", count, " ", (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
    });
  });
});

module.exports = app;

OUTPUT:
Server listening on port 3000
1   1734895723096
2   1734895724902
3   1734895726833
4   1734895728674
pbkdf2  1   8.055
GET /test 200 20 - 8058.565 ms
5   1734895731157
pbkdf2  2   8.181
GET /test 200 20 - 8181.559 ms
6   1734895733084
pbkdf2  3   8.355
GET /test 200 20 - 8355.069 ms
7   1734895735188
pbkdf2  4   8.433
GET /test 200 20 - 8433.176 ms
8   1734895737107
pbkdf2  5   8.478
GET /test 200 20 - 9019.187 ms
pbkdf2  6   8.436
GET /test 200 20 - 9007.400 ms
pbkdf2  7   8.384
GET /test 200 20 - 9470.814 ms
pbkdf2  8   8.19
GET /test 200 20 - 9071.279 ms

Question: Why the 5th request's middleware is not called before one of the previous 4 requests has sent the response. I understand that the crypto.pbkdf2() function for last 4 requests occupies the 4 threads in thread pool, but how is it related to the '/test' middleware execution.
Command to run: export UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=4 && yarn start
